# Kernel Density Estimation on a Log-Scale: Log Transformation vs. Geometric Space

Tags: logarithm, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I’m working on a project where I need to plot a Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) on a log-scale x-axis. I’ve come across two different methods and I’m unsure which one would be more appropriate for my data.

The first method involves log-transforming the dataset before running the KDE, and then exponentiating it (the inverse of the log function) for plotting.
The second method involves generating the KDE using a geometric space instead of the typically used linear space.

Could someone please help me understand the mathematical implications of these two methods? Specifically, how might they affect the resulting KDE and its interpretation? Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated.